# How to Reposition the place of image button view at run time?

Tags: android, gridview, imagebutton

I want to design an activity in which,I need to reposition the place of a image in the grid view based on the hit rate (count) of image button.Followings are my doubts regarding the same

1.How to set the count for an image button?

2.How to reposition the image at run time?

Comment: what you have tried? Reposition in which place? can you show some design?

Comment: @Chintan Rathod Thanx for ur prompt reply! i yet to design any. what all i have to do  is  sort the image button in an activity based on it's hit rate!

Comment: tell me how much do you know about adapter?

Comment: recently i 've used a custom array adapter for list view!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are some ideas for your application.

1) Create one **Bean** class which has some count variable inside.
2) Then create a **BaseAdapter** or **ArrayAdapter** which work for *GridView*.
3) In that adpater, create dynamic Buttons. And set number of count on them.
4) Write a **OnClick** method for every button, which will increase their count which you have defined in **Bean** class.
5) After successfully done, sort that array list based on count like following.

```
Collections.sort(beanData, new Comparator<Bean>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Bean bean1, Bean bean2) {
        if (bean1.getCount() > bean2.getCount()) {
            return -1;
        }  else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir i 'll experiment it and let you know the consequences ! ! !